# How do I add lines in between paragraphs from inputted textarea text?

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating a small webpage that will act as a teleprompter. Users arrive at the page, copy and paste text into a text area, and that text is then displayed in teleprompter like fashion. The text will most likely be copied from Google Drive or office.

My question is how do I add blank lines in between paragraphs (like when Enter has been pressed) when I take the text from the text area into a < p > tag using java script?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take the new lines (`\n`) from the text area and convert them to `<br />`. Something like this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/62bfv61d/1/ should work for you.